# An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpython, postgresql-15

Just so you understand my case:
Recently I was trying to install plpython3u on postgresql 15, and with a lot of struggle I managed
I set the python environment variables (both for system and user) and I also set the environment variables requested on this site:
[ADB Docs](https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/language_pack/latest/installing/windows/)

So to run the plpython3u function I did:

```html
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpython3u;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION saudacao_simples()
RETURNS TEXT AS $$
  mensagem = 'Olá, mundo!'
  return mensagem
$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;
```

the extension is installed successfully, but my function does not run, why?
I get the error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:161)
at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:128)
at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:113)
at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:73)
at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:453)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2120)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:496)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:413)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:333)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:319)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:295)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:290)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.execute(JDBCStatementImpl.java:330)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.executeStatement(JDBCStatementImpl.java:131)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeStatement(SQLQueryJob.java:600)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.lambda$2(SQLQueryJob.java:503)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:190)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeSingleQuery(SQLQueryJob.java:510)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.extractData(SQLQueryJob.java:962)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.SQLEditor$QueryResultsContainer.readData(SQLEditor.java:4130)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.lambda$0(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:123)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:190)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.run(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:121)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetViewer$ResultSetDataPumpJob.run(ResultSetViewer.java:5148)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.runtime.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:105)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

I tried reinstalling the plpython extension, restarting postgresql and I also tried reestablishing new connections, but nothing helped

Comment: 1) The error is coming from dbBeaver and Java  2) You show the function creation not running the function. Add to your question the command you used to run the function. 3) Try running the function `psql` and see what happens.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver the error is happening when trying to create the function, when I try to create it I receive this error that I mentioned

Comment: The function works for me on Ubuntu 22.04 using `psql`.

Comment: I understand.. using psql I get the error: server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or during request processing.
Connection to the server has been lost. Reset attempt: successful.
Could this be linked to an error in my environment variables or in the installation of plpython3u? @AdrianKlaver

Comment: The server crashed. The PostgreSQL log file will tell you some more.

Comment: Hard to tell, though from your previous question things like *... dll C:\Python\Python310\python310.dll to C:\Windows\System32\python33.dll ...* would not be helpful. 1) Follow advice from @LaurenzAlbe 2) Verify that you have undo all the 'cheats' you did before.